# How can we change this information, when we create an envelope through PHP API?

Tags: php, docusignapi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWUkh.png)

On Evelope Dfinition creation, we tried:

```
$user_info = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\UserInfo([
      'account_id' => 'b9711345....2',
      'email' => 'user@domin.com.br',
      'user_id' => 'ae5...87',
      'user_name' => 'Foo Bar',
    ]);

   $envelope_definition->setSender($user_info);
```

but it has no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information pertains to the sender account.
When you authenticate to the API before making tha PHP API call to get an access token, you have to use some user's credentials. That user's information will be used when the envelope is sent.

`user_info` is a read-only endpoint, you cannot update it using the API.

You can change the name of the user via this endpoint - [Users: Update](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/users/users/update/)

The other thing you see is the company name, you need this endpoint to change it - [Accounts: UpdateAccount](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/accounts/accounts/updatesettings/)